# IOS9 webapp orientation issue - Sencha version 1.0

Tags: ios, web-applications, safari, sencha-touch, ios9

We are using Sencha1.0 for our webapp development. In IOS9 version we are facing the following issues.
On initial page load, the page looks fine. When you try to change the device orientation to landscape and back to portrait, all images icons and texts are resized(small). 
We tried -webkit-transform : rotate(-90); its doesnt work. 
Please suggest the cause and any solution for this.

Comment: This so called "Sencha1.0" what version of Sencha Touch does it have? Also iOS 9 is quite a new, it might be a bug in Sencha Touch itself, does it also happens on iOS8?

Comment: no, we don't face the issue with iOS 8. The issue is occurring only for iOS9 and Android4 version devices.

Comment: And what version of Sencha Touch are you using?  This might be a bug, which has been fixed in the later release. Check the [release notes](http://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.4.2/release-notes.html), if you are not sure what version are you running, just execute in the console Ext.version. Because if it works correctly on iOS8 it seems like a framework bug.

Comment: We are using Sench touch 1.1.1 . Please let me know if there is any work around for this issue, without changing upgrading the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Touch 1.1.1 is really quite old version of the framework.

And there is a lot of bug fixes already applied to the framework. The new version of the mobile OS often break a thing or two. You will be also probably seeing [an issue on Android devices](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?301975-Chrome-43-Ext.form.Panel-not-rendering) which runs Chrome 43+

If you already have an App finished and this is the only problem you see, you might fix this by applying override. ( You can check the newer version of the framework and took the part which fixes the issue ) - but it might be really hard to find. Also you probably can't even reach to Sencha support, as the Touch 1 is no longer supported.

But if you are developing the new App, **best option for you is to upgrade** to Touch 2.4.2

The major release of [Sencha Touch](https://www.sencha.com/products/touch/#overview) should be free to download.

*I know that this won't fix the issue but by answer is too long for a comment.*